# Search youtube videos by category in Android

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am developing an android app that searchs for youtube videos, that i want to regroup the results by categories (Documentaries, Music, Education...)

I checked the  [Youtube Data API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) but i did not find something relevant for Android.

Any help will be **very much** appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this:

[youtube data api search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) there is a java code example you can use for your application, and once you have the query variable initialized you can set the videoCategory to the id you want for example:

query.setVideoCategory("35");

here you can find the categories id for youtube videos: [youtube videos categories Id](https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c)

I hope that helps.